# Does Excel always calculate hidden rows?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

If I have Excel sheets with long filtered lists, and I recalculate while a filter is applied, when I remove or change filters, can I always guarantee that Excel will have already calculated all hidden rows properly?

My spreadsheet takes a couple of minutes to calculate, and I usually F9 just to make sure, but is this completely unnecessary?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes Excel always calculates hidden rows unless your formula or VBA code is ignoring hidden rows on purpose. You can take a look at this [Technet](http://blogs.technet.com/b/hub/archive/2010/01/13/excelling-at-excel-hidden-cells-and-subtotals.aspx) blog for more information. Here is a relevant quote tho.

> Normally, hiding rows won't interfere with any formulas so your
>   results will remain the same even if values are called from hidden
>   cells.

Comment: I'll be honest, I'm still worried, but thanks haha

Comment: As with everything take it with a grain of salt lol.

Comment: hmmmm I just can't decide whether I actually feel confident doing it still :/   could save me a lot of time but still

Comment: @Some_Guy if you're worried, then just try it out in a new spreadsheet.